# jQuery Move div with arrow keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrow-keys

I'm trying to move a div using the arrow keys. I have the following code which is not working for me. Do you see anything wrong with it. **Check jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/N5Ltt/1/**

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch (e.which) {
    case 37:
        $('div').stop().animate({
            left: '-= 10'
        }); //left arrow key
        break;
    case 38:
        $('div').stop().animate({
            top: '-= 10'
        }); //up arrow key
        break;
    case 39:
        $('div').stop().animate({
            left: '+= 10'
        }); //right arrow key
        break;
    case 40:
        $('div').stop().animate({
            top: '+= 10'
        }); //bottom arrow key
        break;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two things you need to do:

1. Your `<div>` needs `position: absolute` or your [`top` and `left`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#position-props) properties won't do anything.
2. jQuery doesn't know what `'-= 10'` means but it does understand `'-=10'`. You might want to go all the way to `'-=10px'` as that's more common but the `px` isn't necessary.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/N5Ltt/2/

You're seeing the animation stop when you hold down an arrow key because you call [`.stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) on each keydown and that stops the animation. The animation works using a timer and `.stop` stops the timer; if the keyboard's repeat rate is faster than the first iteration of the timer then no animation happens when you hold down an arrow key. You're only moving by 10px at a time so you could just do a straight non-animated move by 10px using [`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$div.css('left', $div.offset().left - 10);
```

Non-animated version: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/N5Ltt/3/

Comment: Great i didn't' know a space after = affects the way it works. One issue i see is, if you press and hold the down arrow key or right arrow key, the box doesn't keep moving, where as if you press and hold the top or left arrow key it keeps moving like it should. Why does this happen

Comment: @Pinkie, his jsFiddle is working perfectly fine in all four directions for me.

Comment: @Sparky672. i'm testing in chrome. Press and hold the right arrow key. The div doesn't keep moving. On the other hand if you press and hold the left arrow key, div will keep moving to the left until you release the key. This may be a bug i don't know.

Comment: @Pinkie: The space issue is a bit bogus but that's how it works. I added an update for the "stopping" issue.

Comment: @Sparky672: All four arrows work the same for me and they all do nothing once the keyboard's repeat kicks in, see my update please.

Comment: Mu, why are you responding to me?  Your original jsFiddle was working perfectly fine in all four directions as I stated before.  @Pinkie, I am in Safari and yes, holding down the right arrow and it keeps moving, same as the other three arrows.

Comment: @Sparky672: The original stops moving for me (in Safari) if I hold down an arrow key long enough for the keyboard to start repeating and I thought you might be interested in my explanation. Maybe my repeat rate is higher than yours.

Comment: Oh, ok, I see.  Originally, I was simply stating that I saw all four arrows behaving the same.