# Simulate 4 way movement with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a simple game in JQUERY and I want to know how to make a simple 4 way movement (up, down, left, right) with JQUERY I have this:

html

```
<div id="dot"></dot> <!-- the character -->
```

jquery

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 37) {

        } else if (e.which == 38){

        } else if (e.which == 39){

        } else if (e.which == 40){

        }
    });
```

EDIT: The movement is to simulate the "Worlds hardest game" which you can find here: http://www.el-juego-mas-dificil-del-mundo.com/. I need it to be soft (I don't know how to explain it xD)

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782266/jquery-move-div-with-arrow-keys

Comment: That movement is not continuous, please check before commenting!

Comment: @mrpinkman oops hold on :)

Comment: @mrpinkman now - how can you tell that this user wants the movement to be continuous? It sure looks a lot like that other question to me.

Comment: he says he is making a game, i suppose that the game requires the movement to be as smooth and continuous as possible, duh

Comment: @mrpinkman that's a pretty big assumption; there are all kinds of games, after all. What if it's a Chess game?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to change your `</dot>` into `</div>`.

This is not the `perfect` answer, but it can be a good start for you. (There is other better optimized ways to do it I'm sure, but I don't have the skills for that).

Then, you can use `.animate()` to move your dot :

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 37) {
        $("#dot").animate({
            left: "-=5"
        }, 5);
    } else if (e.which == 38) {
        $("#dot").animate({
            top: "-=5"
        }, 5);
    } else if (e.which == 39) {
        $("#dot").animate({
            left: "+=5"
        }, 5);
    } else if (e.which == 40) {
        $("#dot").animate({
            top: "+=5"
        }, 5);
    }
});
```

And set your div `position` as `absolute`:

```
.dot {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/6c5kpj69/